# Debug Node JS code in VS Code bundled with Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, webpack, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Node JS, and JS development in general. I have an app-bundle.js file that is bundled by WebPack, that is called through an app.js file.

I am trying to debug using Visual Studio Code. I created the launch.json file for the VS code configuration. However, when I insert breakpoints in the individual js files, I get

`Breakpoints set, but not yet bound`

However, when I set a breakpoint in app.js or app.bundle.js, it works fine.

My launch.json is below:

```
{
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js"
}
```

How can I get the VS code debugger to work with the individual js files?

Comment: Does running it directly with NodeJS have the same result?

Comment: When I insert `debugger;` at the same line where I set the breakpoint with VS code, it stops at the breakpoint, and points to the line in the bundled file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue.

As `debug` is deprecated, use `inspect`. Therefore, add the following to the script object in `package.json` to build using webpack and start node in debug mode with 9229 as the local port:

```
"start": "webpack && node --inspect--brk=9229 app.js"
```

As webpack bundles the js files into one, we need a sourcemap, so that VS code can use breakpoints on the individual files. Therefore, in `webpack.config.js`, add the `SourceMapDevToolPlugin`:

```
plugins:[
    new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
        filename: '[name].js.map'
    })
]
```

Finally in **VS Code**, configure the launch.json file as follow:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Program"

    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "args": [],
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder},
    "preLaunchTask": null,
    "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "run-script", "start"
    ],
    "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
    },
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "port": 9229
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me, I can debug my bundle, but it won't map back the my original .ts files in my src/ directory

Comment: Didn't work for me neither. @MikeHaas I'm facing the same issue as you, Could you be able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

1. Change the **vs-code** debug configuration file.
2. Add a `npm-script` command debug same as the run-script value above.
3. Start Debugging **F5**.

Configuration content:

```
{
    "name": "Launch via NPM",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "run-script", "debug"
    ],
    "port": 9229
}
```

Reference:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[Official Doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging)